# Whats exactly mean by build, ship and run any app, anywhere with Docker

Tags: docker

Docker says "it possible to build, ship and run any app, anywhere"
Dockerising the app looks promising solution to ship and run any app, anywhere with less pain.
But how it's going to help us in building an application?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few interesting use cases at build time for docker.

- You could use docker to brink up database with known state inside containers for your integration tests to hit. using the [Docker Maven Plugin](http://www.ofbizian.com/2014/04/a-docker-maven-plugin-for-integration.html).
- Having a predefined container for your application which will not change during the development cycle is useful. Especially as you can use the same container when you go to prod deployments. This is different from say vagrant which you would not use for your production deployment.
- Since there are so many docker containers already available your would not need to spend time figuring out how to deploy and mange all the various tools and services your deployment may need.